# Class Not found : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet

Tags: eclipse, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

In spring-hibernate project, I have added all jars required in some User created library in eclipse. But still it is giving the exception that, 
ServletDispatcher is not available. Below all jar files included are shown, just help me which one I left.

```
org.springframework.aop-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.asm-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.aspects-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.beans-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.context.support-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.context-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.expression-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.instrument.tomcat-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.instrument-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.jdbc-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.jms-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.orm-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.oxm-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.test-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.transaction-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web.portlet-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web.struts-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
hibernate3.jar
jstl.jar
standard.jar
org.springframework.webflow-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar
```

StackTrace is:

```
SEVERE: Servlet /PersonLoanManegment threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1711)              
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:525)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:507)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:124)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1136)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5015)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5302)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1566)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1556)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: This happening at the time of deployment? If yes, just adding the required jars to user library and referring that in eclipse build path is not sufficient. You should check that your .war having those jars or not!

Answer (score 8):

I found adding to the POM:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
  <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Added the needing file and IntelliJ was able to resolve the DispatcherServlet.

Comment: Thanks! spring-webmvc dependency has this Class.

Answer (score 3):

You need jar spring-web-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar in your classpath. With Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Regards

Answer (score 2):

You need jar `org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar` in your classpath. Which contains `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet`

Comment: I think the dependency is `spring-webmvc` - http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/3.2.4.RELEASE/.

Comment: Even after adding spring-webmvc it is giving same exception

Comment: @PavelHoral I tried adding commons.logging also. But still not getting it.

Comment: Thanks! spring-webmvc dependency has this Class.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very old question

According to an article I read "Most probably the necessary Spring MVC related jar files are not loaded and deployed on tomcat startup. But note: these files are in your classpath and hence you are not getting any error in Eclipse IDE during development time. Happens only during runtime."

This is how I resolved mine:

1. Right Click on Project.
2. Choose Properties.
3. Click Deployment Assembly.
4. Click on Add.
5. Select "Java Build Path Entries"
6. Select Maven Dependencies and finish.

Clean the project and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, it's not because you lost dependency configuration. you should check whether the jar is really available, follow this:

package your project, then unzip it, check: /WEB-INF/lib, see if the org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar exists! if yes, unzip this jar, see if it's corrupt! it it's not existing or corrupt, check your maven repository, you can remove this artifact from your maven repository, and rebuild, let maven re-download it. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you come across ClassNotFound exceptions try to find the missing jar using the various online tools like [jarFinder](http://www.jarfinder.com)